# Any way to remotely connect to an IP address outside the network i'm using?

Tags: java, ssh, raspberry-pi, vnc

What i want to do is to remotely access my Raspberry Pi that is using a Maestro modem using my computer connected to a LAN.I have managed to configure my Pi's IP address to be static. Can someone help.  [I have been following this tutorial](http://http:/https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc.pdf)

Comment: This is definitely answerable by google. I am sorry.

Comment: The problem i'm having is that i don't have access to the router where the modem used by Raspberry Pi is connected, so it's impossible for me to do port forwarding. My question is that is there any option besides port forwarding?

Comment: How can you have no access to the modem? No I'm afraid there is no other legal way aside from port forwarding... Why don't you have access?

Answer (score 1):

The only method to achieve a connection would be if one device has a routable IP address.  If the machine you wish to access the Pi from is routable (either no NAT, or port forwarding CAN be configured at that end) then you could establish a connection from the Pi to the PC.
I see you have tagged VNC, there are instructions on how to do exactly this on the [RealVNC website](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.2/guides/user/aj1077505.html).

Comment: Thank you so much this tutorial explains well, i think it will be very useful.